# SDE representation implies differentiability? (Converse of Ito's Lemma)

Tags: derivatives, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm trying to establish that a function is differentiable when the value of the function follows an SDE. In a sense, I am trying to establish a converse of Ito's Lemma. More specifically, I know two pieces of information:

1. I know that a process $(\xi_t)_{t\ge0}$ follows an SDE
   $$
   d \xi_t = (\delta \xi_t - X_t)dt + \omega_t dW_t, 
   $$
   where $(W_t)_{t\ge 0}$ is a standard Brownian motion and $(X_t)_{t \ge 0}$ is some adapted process. $(\omega_t)_{t\ge 0}$ is also an adapted process.
2. I also know that $\xi_t = G(Y_t, V_t)$ for a continuous function $G$. Here, $(Y_t)_{t\ge 0}$ and $(V_t)_{t\ge 0}$ are two adapted processes, with volatilities $\sigma_Y(Y_t,V_t)$ and $\sigma_V(Y_t,V_t)$, respectively.

Based on this information, can I conclude that
$$
   \omega_t = G_Y(Y_t,V_t) \sigma_Y(Y_t,V_t) + G_V(Y_t,V_t) \sigma_V(Y_t,V_t)?
$$
Or, more generally, can I conclude that the function $G$ is differentiable?